# Mifare authorizations on Android with strange behavior

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I'm faced with a weird  behavior. Key A and B have the right to read block 0 & 1 & 2. (Access condition is set to : 6E1789)
But I can only read with key A, because with key B, Android application detect a new NFC Tag and lost the last one, so she goes "onPause" then "onNewIntent", and this over and over...

Here my function to read data (it's the same for key A but authenticateSectorWithKeyB is replaced by authenticateSectorWithKeyA of course).

```
public byte[] readOneSectorOneBlockKeyB(byte[] key, int sectorNumber, int blockNumber) throws MifareException {
        byte[] data = null;
        try {
            boolean auth = false;
            int bIndex = 0;
            auth = mfc.authenticateSectorWithKeyB(sectorNumber, key);
            if (auth) {
                bIndex = 0;
                bIndex = mfc.sectorToBlock(sectorNumber);
                data = mfc.readBlock(bIndex + blockNumber);
            } else {
                throw new MifareException("Authentification failed");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new MifareException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return data;
    }
```

And system doesn't catch an IOException ...
I don't know where the problem is from ?

Comment: So are you catching all your own exceptions?

Comment: Not quite clear what you are doing. Does this happen when reading A, then B, or even if try to read only B? Most probably the card is resetting the authentication state, which is seen as `onNewIntent()` on the app side.

Comment: @Thomas, I catch IOException in above method and I throw my own Exception (MifareException) to make the difference with other NFC Tech.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov, This happen when I try to read with key B, everything is fine when reading with key A. Is there a way to not resetting authentification state ? Thx

Comment: Does it work with another app like NFCTag Info: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo

Comment: Yes, it works good with this by only referencing key B

Comment: Another thing, when I execute the above method in debug mode, I get an auth=true, but on line readBlock I get a "transceive failed" which is catch in IOException ... Real time comportement is different from the step to step one ...

Comment: @NikolayElenkov, question: is it really important, that NFC operation are done in a different thread than the activity one ?

Comment: If you are stepping through the debugger this will likely timeout and reset the card. If you don't start a new thread, it's executed in the main/UI thread. Don't do this.

Comment: Ok, I will do some modification and put Mifare operations in an AsyncTask or IntentService. But I curious about the raisons for not doing this kind of operations in Main/UI thread, do you know why ? Expect the fact UI can be blocked, I don't see why UI can disturb Mifare operation ... anyway. I will give soon a respons of this futur work.

Comment: It seems that doing operation in a dedicated thread does not change anything. I've made a temporary patch with an Aynctask which detects when card is removed (isConnected()). If card has not been removed before onNewIntent I ignore new Intent ... not very clean I agree